# Sorting issue with 'Date' columns in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm using `handsontable` in a project and currently facing some issues with sorting the `Date` columns. It seems like a bug as if you look at the demonstration in their website you'll see that it doesn't work their either:

[Handsontable with Date Column](http://handsontable.com/demo/date.html)

So, the question is, is that a known bug? If not, why it's not even working in their demo? I just followed their examples so you can imagine I've the same code running in my machine.

Would it be okay to write the dates like these `2013/05/21`, `2013/07/12`, `2013/12/01` so that might sort fine like strings?

Also can I add a hidden column, containing some numbers in a correct sort as the dates are, like `1,2,3,...`, then when you trying to sort via the date column, I sort it by that hidden-numeric column instead? (well, sounds tricky, so any other ideas are really appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed a known bug in the current version.

See this open issue:
https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/720